Unable to Connect to Internet After Deleting NetworkManager on Artix Linux
I recently deleted NetworkManager from my Artix Linux system running Runit, and now I'm unable to connect to the internet. I've tried several solutions but haven't been successful. Here's what I've attempted so far:

I don't have DHCP installed nor IWD.
I tried installing the NetworkManager package from source, and also attempted to transfer it via USB. However, when I run makepkg -i, I consistently encounter missing dependencies. I've tried installing these dependencies one by one, but eventually, I encounter an error during makepkg because it's trying to clone something from a git repository online.

I'm stuck at this point and not sure how to proceed. Any guidance on resolving this . Thank you

If your system is not already set up for building packages from source, trying to install all the required development dependencies for building NetworkManager without having an internet connection or a local repository mirror is going to be way too much trouble.
Get a binary package of NetworkManager from here: https://archive.artixlinux.org/packages/n/ (although this archive has had some connectivity issues recently)
or here: https://archive2.artixlinux.org/packages/n/
You might need at least the networkmanager and networkmanager-runit packages, and maybe others depending on your desktop environment choices and whether or not you use a VPN.
Then install them with:
pacman -U /path/to/package/package_name-version.pkg.tar.zst

If you need other packages for dependencies, get binary packages for them until you get at least the basic network connection up. After that, you can build things from source if you really want.
If you don't like NetworkManager, then you might instead get a binary package of a DHCP client you like, and then configure it... but going back to NetworkManager first, then changing your setup only after you've restored basic internet connectivity will probably be easier, and you'll have access to resources such as the Artix Wiki and the Arch Wiki for advice.
